# Proper configuration for apt-proxy that gracefully fails

Tags: proxy, apt

I use the following for my apt proxy configuration:

```
Acquire {
   Retries "3";
   HTTP { Proxy "http://10.9.2.21:3142"; };
 };
```

My understanding of this syntax was that apt would try the proxy 3 times and revert to the original target after the third. This is not happening. Today I tried to do an apt update while the node with the proxy was shutdown. I expected a delay followed by apt-get working from the base debian repo.

Instead, when I do this:

```
apt install nginx
```

I get this:

```
Err:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libjpeg62-turbo amd64 1:1.5.2-2+b1
  Could not connect to 10.9.2.21:3142 (10.9.2.21). - connect (113: No route to host)
....
....
...
..
.
etc
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.2-2+b1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to 10.9.2.21:3142 (10.9.2.21). - connect (113: No route to host)
....
....
...
..
.
etc
```

So when my proxy is down, I'm not even sure IF it's retrying 3 times (ie. no output suggested it) and it's clearly not falling back to anything.

I am now seeking whatever additional syntax will get me the functionality that I originally thought that I had: when proxy fails, after set retries, apt gets from the original target.

Is this possible? Can anyone share how to do it? Half an hour of searching around the interweb has yielded me nothing.

Comment: telnet 10.9.2.21 3142 to check if connectivity is working

Comment: That is not what a proxy is.